# Ruby JSON parser justified in not liking whitespace?

Tags: ruby, json

I'm using json_pure-1.4.6 and it's having trouble parsing data from Chrome's SpeedTracer. In particular it is failing like this:

```
705: unexpected token at '{"type":2147483642,"time":8872.551025390625,"data":{"identifier":1,"time":1295485209.698246,"request":{"url":"http://localhost:3000/login/new","httpMethod":"GET","httpHeaderFields":{"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0'
```

That's clearly an incomplete statement, but in the file itself it looks like this:

```
{"type":2147483642,"time":8872.551025390625,"data":{"identifier":1,"time":1295485209.698246,"request":{"url":"http://localhost:3000/login/new","httpMethod":"GET","httpHeaderFields":{"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_5; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.634.0 Safari/534.16","Accept":"application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"}},"redirectResponse":{"isNull":true}},"sequence":116}
```

I tried running it through JSONLint and it didn't complain:

```
{
    "type": 2147483642,
    "time": 8872.551025390625,
    "data": {
        "identifier": 1,
        "time": 1295485209.698246,
        "request": {
            "url": "http://localhost:3000/login/new",
            "httpMethod": "GET",
            "httpHeaderFields": {
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_5; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.634.0 Safari/534.16",
                "Accept": "application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"
            }
        },
        "redirectResponse": {
            "isNull": true
        }
    },
    "sequence": 116
}
```

Since it fails at the white space, I tried removing all of the white space in the "User-Agent" line and json_pure then parsed it without error. Is this a json_pure bug?

Comment: Thanks to Bill, I took another harder look at just what the parser was trying to parse. Turns out my problem was just me making a DUMB MISTAKE. I was culling all of the JSON data out of the HTML and trying to deal with it as one-statement-per-line. Unfortunately, I was doing an unqualified "split" so it was splitting on every white space, not every linefeed. The SpeedTrace data I originally tested with had no generic whitespace which contributed to my confusion. Switching to 'split "\n"' solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just pasted the JSON string into a file, and then ran:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json/pure'
str = File.open('pasted.json').read
x = JSON.parse(str)
```

...and got the expected value with no errors.

```
ruby -v
  => ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-darwin9.8.0]
gem list json_pure
  => json_pure (1.4.6)
```

Clearly, there's something wacky going on with your setup, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Hmm. That is good info, thanks. I'll see what the deal is an post an update.

Comment: I figured it out, adding the comment on to the main section.